# Data validation / Sanitization callback function

Tags: wordpress, sanitization

I added a section to the customizer of my WP theme that allows a user to change which categories display on the first page of the theme. However, when checking with the Theme Check plugin, it returned the following error:

REQUIRED: Found a Customizer setting that did not have a sanitization callback function. Every call to the add_setting() method needs to have a sanitization callback function passed.
I have no idea how to add this function to my code. If you can help, here’s the code:

http://pastebin.com/xksf3vWd

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Customizer does not handle validation and sanitization of the user input values. It is therefore essential to sanitize these values before saving them to the database.

The [add_setting()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting) method of the WP_Customizer object accepts an 'sanitize_callback' argument, that can be used to specify a sanitization callback. So, in every add_setting() call, add the sanitization callback function.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'first_category', array(
    'default'           => 'Uncategorized',     // The default category name.
    'sanitize_callback' => 'ys_sanitize_category',  // Sanitize callback function name
) );
```

The Sanitize callback function:

```
function ys_sanitize_category( $category ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $category, array( 'Uncategorized', 'Blogposts', 'News' ) ) ) { // Add the names of your categories here. Use get_categories() to fetch them dynamically.
        $category = 'Uncategorized';
    }
    return $category;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Glad that it worked. Regarding the other problem, did it exist before adding the sanitize callback code?

Comment: Thank you, @Hareesh Sivasubramaniar,

When I add your code, the errors are gone but when I use the Customizer and change the category of a particular section on the front page, the posts for the section do not load. Instead, I have a blank section. 

Do you have an idea what causes this?

Comment: The problem didn't exist before adding your code and your code looks correct, which makes me wonder why this is happening.

Comment: I think that the problem is in the "if" statement of your function. When I remove it, everything displays correctly on the front end.

Comment: Removing the if condition will nullify the functionality of the sanitize function.
Did you remember to replace the names of your categories within the if statement?

Comment: Yes, it will replace the sanitize function's functionality. I replaced the categories as follows:

`function ys_sanitize_category( $category ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $category, array( 'World', 'Business', 'Sport', 'Entertainment' ) ) ) { // Add the names of your categories here. Use get_categories() to fetch them dynamically.
        $category = 'Uncategorized';
    }
    return $category;
}`

Comment: If I replace the condition of your if statement with this one, it works just fine:
`    if ( ! is_string ( $category ) ) { 
        $category = 'Uncategorized';
    }`